# Can I convert my velocity 9-speed rear road hub to bolt-on?

Tags: wheels, hub, axle, through-axle

I have an older velocity wheelset with their standard 9-speed road hubs. Can I convert these hubs (particularly the rear hub) to bolt on?

Answer (score 1):

You could get locking skewers (e.g. [pitlock](http://www.pitlock.com/)) or skewers which have hex bolts (e.g. [this](http://www.wiggle.com/halo-hex-key-skewers-pair/)) [obviously, having a hex key or a 15 mm wrench isn't really secure, but pitlock is more secure], if you want it for the security. But all you need to do is run down to your bike shop with your wheel+skewer and get them to match it to an appropriate solid axle in most cases if you really want a solid axle (since you didn't specify exactly which hub you have, we can't really give more details).

Comment: Also, this hub: http://www.velocityusa.com/product/hubs/road-rear-hub

Comment: They might be cheap skewers? You shouldn't get sliding if you have good skewers which bite into the drop outs well.

Comment: True. Probably cheap skewers. I could also use a chain tensioner like surly tuggnut on the drive side to help avoid slipping, but I really liked my old wheels which had bolt on hubs. Never had any issue with them on this bike and it's harder to over tighten them to the point of damage.  However, the rims became concave with excessive use and the hubs use loose-ball bearings which probably won't survive on my winter bike as long as sealed bearing hubs. 

I'll be heading down to my shop in a few days and see what they have to say about it.